# turning multiple nested files into a single file (concatenating them)

Tags: python

I have a folder consisting of 7 files, each having several text files inside. I intend to read through them and write each of those nested text files into a single file called ZebraAllRaw.txt. In the end, there must be only one single file containing all the text files that existed in each of those 7 files.

This is the function I have written:

```
def CombineFiles(folder):
     with open('D:/ZebraAllRaw.txt', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as OutFile:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder, topdown= False):
            for filename in files:
                file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
                with open(file_path, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
                    content = f.read()
                    new_content = content.replace('\n', '')
                    OutFile.write(new_content + "\n")
```

However, it seems that all the content is written into the new file 9 times, as if it had read through them more than expected.

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables - you will see which file you read. Or maybe you have the same content in 9 files.

Comment: The content in each file is different.

Comment: or maybe you run `CombineFiles` 9 times - you use mode `"a"` so you append to existing file

Comment: as I said before - use `print()` - it will show you which file you read, what content you write, how may times you read the same file, etc.

Comment: I intend to append all files to each other, in order to have only one file left in the end. The function is not called 9 times.

Comment: as I said before - use print() -and you will see all what code is doing. Or learn how to use debuger.

Comment: maybe function is called only once but you may run script 9 times and then mode "a" will append to existing file - it will not remove previous content when you run script again. You may use `print()` to display file content before you write new content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you con't append the files from different runs.

I only replaced the file mode *append* with *write* at the open

```
def CombineFiles(folder):
     with open('D:/ZebraAllRaw.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as OutFile: # mode "w", not "a"
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder, topdown= False):
            for filename in files:
                file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
                with open(file_path, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
                    content = f.read()
                    new_content = content.replace('\n', '')
                    OutFile.write(new_content + "\n")
```